# Sass::SyntaxError on Rails Production Precompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, production, precompile

I tried to precompile my project on production but it gives me this error and I don't know as to where it is pointing to since it's really vague.

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "@media print"
  (in /home/deploy/production/project-name/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css)
(sass):124
```

The path links to the manifest file of the admin/ folders of my assets.
Some of the stylesheets' format is .css.scss.erb.

Comment: its syntax error in your admin.css file.. at line 124 may be you missing a ';'

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sass files` in your `app/assets/` directory.

I think you're using sprockets in your admin.css at line 124?
You'll see the file you want to include having an sass syntax error.

Example:

```
# app/assets/admin.css
/* ..
(line 124) * require my-file
.. */
```

now you should look for the `my-file`.